# How can I get the count depending on the column value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have this table in SQL Server

```
name    type    date
aaa     A       2016-05-05
aaa     A       2016-05-22
aaa     B       2016-05-21
bbb     A       2016-05-15
bbb     B       2016-05-01
```

and I want to make a query to get this result

```
name    count(type)
aaa     2.5
bbb     1.5
```

NB : for A the count must increase with 1, and for B with 0.5 because I have this rule :

```
count(type)=count(A)+count(B)/2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE type WHEN 'A' THEN 1.0 WHEN 'B' THEN 0.5 END)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: u forget to put (THEN) after 'B'

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    SUM(
        CASE type 
            WHEN 'B' THEN 0.5 
            WHEN 'A' THEN 1 
        END)
FROM <Table Name>
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE to do a calculation like follows:
    SELECT SUM(CASE 
                WHEN Type = 'A' 
                   THEN 1 
                   ELSE 0 
           END) as SumA, SUM(CASE 
                WHEN Type = 'B' 
                   THEN 0.5 
                   ELSE 0 
           END)  as Sum220
    FROM Your Table